# javascript setTimeout within a loop [closure]

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me the working of this code.

```
var display = function(i) {
  return function(){
    console.log(i);
  };
};

for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  setTimeout(display(i), i*1000);
}
```

From what I reckon is the display function is called in each iteration.
Or is it called after the loop has finished executing then the timeout is triggered?

Comment: It will get called after loop has finished executing.

Answer (score 4):

The for iteration will run 5 times quickly, and it be equal to running these lines:

```
 setTimeout(display(0), 0*1000);
 setTimeout(display(1), 1*1000);
 ...
 setTimeout(display(4), 4*1000);
```

The result would be:

```
 display(0) will launch after 0 seconds.
 display(1) will launch after 1 seconds.
 ...
 display(4) will launch after 4 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

you loop runs as it should but the display will be called on each `setTimeout` interval value in it.
so as per above code sample:it will do something like ->

first call after `1 sec`,second after `2 sec` and so on i.e. it will make that many copy of the same portion of code with passed time interval and will run as the time comes.